# What is causing a clacking knocking like sound on my toyota camry 1999

Tags: engine, toyota, camry

I got the heads redone by a engine tech, but for some reason after it starts I get this clacking knocking like sound. The timing is correct. I'm assuming the firing order is correct as well, But just to be on the safe side, in case it is not, does anyone know the exact precise order for 1999 Toyota Camry?

Hope I can get some answers. Thank you all in advance. Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a firing order problem. If many cyliders are firing at the wrong time, the engine probably wouldn't run. I have had a loose spark plug wire on one cylinder, and it isn't a "clacking knocking like sound" when a 4-cylinder engine is running on 3 cylinders.

Comment: Can you take a video and post it on youtube so everyone can here it.  Put the link in your question.  :)   Happy New Year!

Comment: From your description, it sounds like lifter/valve train noise, but I can't be sure without hearing it.

Answer (score 2):

The firing order is ***1, 3, 4, 2***

[image]

**Coils and Sparkplug Wires**

[image]